# Understanding regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string

Tags: java, regex

The following code is used to remove html tags from the string

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
```

The following code also gives the same result:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","");
```

What is the difference? Why should we add double slash at the front?

What is the use of . in regex? Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Have you tried reading documentation? There is nice javadoc out there, explaining the meaning of all elements of characters in regular expressions. The dot is a wildcard matching any character btw.

Comment: *Why should we add double slash at the front?* - You shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not needed. As you pointed out, both do the same thing. Here is why...

In Java Regular expressions, `\\` is a single backslash. Backslashes are used to escape the next character. The next character is a `<` which does not need to be escaped, therefore the `\\<` is redundant, and can be replaced with just `<`.

Look here for characters that have special meaning and/or need to be escaped:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Say you were trying to match a `?` instead of the `<`, then you would use a regex like `\\?`.

*To match a single backslash, you would need 4 backslashes `\\\\` in your regex.*

Also note, If you were to type this line into an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA, it will highlight it and say:

> Redundant character escape '\\<' in RegExp